# Trying to draw a parallelogram on this gray band. Why does it *sometimes* not align with the gray band?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, geometry

To make it simple, I'm working with one contour, which is a very close approximation to a parallelogram. I need to draw a line through the contour such that the line fits under the contour perfectly.

Here's a minimum reproducible example:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from math import dist

# setup stuff
filler_img = np.zeros((1600, 1600), dtype=np.uint8)
cnt = np.array([[490, 885], [648, 1065], [636, 1201], [486, 1026]])  # [[733, 712], [897, 886], [688, 1006], [528, 828]]
c1, c2, c3 = cnt[:-1]
moments = cv2.moments(cnt)
center = (int(moments["m10"] / moments["m00"]), int(moments["m01"] / moments["m00"]))  # (x, y)

# calculating pass-through line
y_to_x_ratio = (c2[1] - c3[1]) / (c3[0] - c2[0])
point1 = (0, int(y_to_x_ratio*center[0] + center[1]))
point2 = (1600, int(-y_to_x_ratio*(1600-center[0]) + center[1]))
cv2.line(filler_img, point1, point2, 100, thickness=int(dist(c1, c2)))   # problems with thcikness argument

# filling circles at c1, c2, and c3
disp_img = cv2.drawContours(cv2.cvtColor(filler_img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR), [cnt], -1, (255, 255, 255), 5)
cv2.circle(disp_img, c1, 20, (0, 0, 255), -1)  # red
cv2.circle(disp_img, c2, 20, (0, 255, 0), -1)  # green
cv2.circle(disp_img, c3, 20, (255, 0, 0), -1)  # blue
imshow(disp_img)
```

Note: `imshow()` is a function that shows images on Jupyter Notebook - it's implementation is below:

```py
def imshow(*imgs: cv2.Mat) -> None:
    def helper(img: cv2.Mat) -> None:
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.grid(False)
        plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
        plt.show()
    for img in imgs:
        helper(img)
```

This is what the code produces:

[image]

As you can see in the code, I've got the calculations correct for the angle of the line. It is based off of corners in the contour, which I've also labeled on the output image: `c1: red, c2: green, c3: blue`. The angle is simply found using `c2` and `c3` (the drawn line is parallel to the line between c2 and c3), and I found the thickness to be the distance between `c1` and `c2` (perpendicular to the drawn line). However, the line drawn is obviously more thick than it should be.

More interestingly, this issue goes away with a different contour. This is the result of the same code, but with the contour in the comment in the `cnt = ...` line:

[image]

As you can see, this is a much better fit of the contour. How can I consistently draw lines that fill the area as accurately as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm dumb. I was using the length of the edge of the parallelogram as my length for thickness, when I really had to do some trig to find the distance between the other sides of the parallelogram:

```
  _____
 / |  /
/__|_/
```

The distance marked with the straight line is what I needed to find.
Here is a calculation for thickness which works:

```py
thickness = int(dist(c1, c2) * abs(sin(atan2(c2[1] - c3[1], c3[0] - c2[0]) - atan2(c2[1] - c1[1], c1[0] - c2[0]))))
```